# Prevent extensions from logging to the Chrome console

Tags: google-chrome-extensions, google-chrome-devtools

Is there a way to prevent Chrome extensions from logging to the Chrome console?

I have a number of extensions installed (Vimium, Stay Focusd, etc.) which all log their loading of JS assets as XHRs in the Chrome console. This makes it difficult to see what the page I am visiting itself is doing. As I use Chrome for debugging mostly, logs from installed extensions are rather interfering than helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `-scheme:chrome-extension` as the filter in the network tab

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4gPU.png)